# Get the right "upper" Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to find out the limit for the sequence $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ 
using the squeeze theorem.

My idea was:

$\frac{n}{n^n} \leq \frac{n!}{n^n} \leq \frac{n!+1}{n^n} $

So the limits of the smaller sequence and the bigger sequence are 0, thus
the limit of the original sequence is 0.

But is the bigger sequence $\frac{n!+1}{n^n}$ a good choice? Or is there
a more obvious sequence to choose?

Comment: You're using the final result to prove that the right sequence's limit is zero.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling approximation for $n!$ ?

Comment: Use that the ratio is $\le \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: In answer to your question, you want to make "bounding" selections (whether they're functions, general terms of a sequence, an infinite series, and so forth) for which you understand their behavior well.  Are you any more sure that $ \ \frac{n! \ + \ 1}{n^n} \ $ approaches zero as $ \ n \ $ goes to infinity than you are about $ \ \frac{n! }{n^n} \ $ ?  If you aren't, then it isn't a "good" choice.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{n!}{n^n} =\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdots \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n}{n}\le \frac{1}{n}.$$ That's because all the factors to the right of $1/n$ are smaller than or equal to $1$. We have equality when $n=1$, with $1/n$ being the *only* factor, and when $n=2$, with $1/n$ being the only factor besides $n/n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {n!}{n^n} =\frac {n \times (n-1)\times \dots \times 2 \times 1}{n^n}\le \frac {\overbrace {n\times n \times \dots \times n}^{{n-1}\text {times}}\times 1}{n^n}=\frac {n^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac1n$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how large or small is $\frac{n!}{n^n}$, for large $n$.

A rather clear answer is given by Stirling's formula that estimates $n!$.  The ratio of interest grows exponentially, at a rate of about $e^n$.

Answer (score 0):

For the left one, I would personally even choose $n! \geq 0$.

For the right one: Use the AM-GM inequality:

$$\frac{2n}{3}>\frac{(n+1)}{2}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}{n} > \sqrt[n]{n!}$$

Therefore $n!< \left(\frac{2}{3}n\right)^n$. I'm sure you can finish it now.

---

A more basic argument:

A half of the terms are smaller than $n/2$, the other half is smaller than $n$, so $$n! \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}n\right)^{n/2}n^{n/2}=\frac{n^n}{2^{n/2}}$$